# how to solve installation error MS Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm

there is a big problems appear when set up MS dynamics server 2016 in microsoft windows server  r2

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CMHdHFgORlOIOwkbHE1fMnukje68ZoWD

Comment: Can you show the whole error? It looks like a permission issue for your service account...

Comment: The account specified to run the Microsoft Dynamics CRM application does not have Performance Counter permissions.

Comment: another error : The account specified to run the Microsoft Dynamics CRM application does not have Performance Counter permissions.

Comment: I believe that is a group in Active Directory

Comment: Hey - if you want help getting the thing setup.... glenn AT gfdatacorp

Comment: hello genn how to contact you

Comment: Email glenn@gfdata.io

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the one of the service accounts you selected is not a member of the local group 'Performance Log Users'. As this group is local to the server, you may get different behaviour on a different server.

Found an article related to the problem - https://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2012/10/09/the-account-specified-to-run-the-microsoft-dynamics-crm-application-does-not-have-performance-counter-permissions/

Hope it helps.